# PHP mail() function,sending mail as HTML code

Tags: php, html

I am facing a problem where when I send mail using `mail()`, it sends the HTML code in the mail. This is my code:

```
<?php
$message = "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>Dear ".$_POST['fname']."&nbsp;".$_POST['lname'].",</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan=2>Thank you for contacting us.We will get back to you in next 48 hrs.Your Contacts Details are as follows:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width='28%' >Title</td>
    <td width='72%'>".$_POST['title']."</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>".$_POST['email']."</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Your Message</td>
    <td>".$_POST['message']."</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>How did you hear about us? </td>
    <td>".$checkBox."</td>
  </tr>
</table>
";  

$subject = "ContactUs";
$headers .= "From: ".$from_mail." \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

mail($_POST["coach"], $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

And the output which I am getting in my e-mail looks like this:

```
<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>Dear Test User,</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan=2>Thank you for contacting us.Your Contacts Details are as follows:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width='28%' >Title</td>
    <td width='72%'>Mr.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>test@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Your Message</td>
    <td>Test Message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>How did you hear about us? </td>
    <td>www.example.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I don't know why is this happening. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
```

also try : [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

Comment: @Tornado yours very welcome also check [this](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.mail-mime.php)

Comment: But I need to confirm that why is it happned if I use `Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n`.

Comment: @Tornado you need to use mime type to send html please check link my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Use

> html_entity_decode()

```
eg. mail($_POST["coach"], $subject, html_entity_decode($message), $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following code in header portion

```
<?php
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
?>
```